# Filter GeoJSON data to a region

Tags: geojson

I am beginner to map plotting. I am currently trying to create some custom map-plots on historical Europe on the datawrapper website.
I have obtained a GeoJSON file from this link (https://github.com/aourednik/historical-basemaps/blob/master/world_1920.geojson)
However, its for the whole world and I need only for Europe in 1920s.
So, is there some way I can generate a custom GeoJSON

(I am inexperienced in tools like ArcGIS)

Edit:
New Github link (https://github.com/aourednik/historical-basemaps/blob/master/geojson/world_1920.geojson)

Comment: You want to filter programmatically or in arcgis?

Comment: You're link does not work, are you open to using QGIS?

Comment: @Binks : I have updated the link and the way in which I managed to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Without using professional GIS, you can

- convert GeoJSON to KML using an online tool (like [this one](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/geojson-to-kml));
- open custom tool [Google MyMaps](https://mymaps.google.com/);
- import KML file;
- remove unnecessary countries (the easiest way to do this is in the list on the left).

You can work with the resulting map yourself, embed it into sites and blogs for others, export data to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it using mapshaper tool available online (https://mapshaper.org/).
Since the GeoJSON was properly formatted for the whole world, mapshaper allowed me to click and select what objects I wanted to remain on my map and what not.